# Obtaining graphics of functions in non-standard analysis

Tags: nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

In the context of $R(\varepsilon)$ or more broad fields, Levi-Civita field or $No(\omega_1)$, how can we obtain the graphics of functions on the infinitesimal range?

For instance, it is alleged that the graphic of standard part or function $f_1(x)=\sin \frac1 x$ on the interval $(-4\varepsilon, 4\varepsilon)$ is as follows (with horizontal 1 corresponding to $\varepsilon$ on the plot), and non-standard part is infinitesimal:

[image]

$$\text{st} \sin \frac1x=\sin \left(\Re\left(\operatorname{arctanh} (x/\varepsilon)\right)\right)$$

and the graphic of $f_2(x)=\cos \frac1x$ on the same interval is

[image]
so that

$$\text{st} \cos \frac1x=\cos \left(\Re\left(\operatorname{arctanh} (x/\varepsilon)\right)\right)$$

The [symmetric full derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205760/has-anybody-ever-considered-full-derivative) of the functions are

$$D_{sym} [\sin \frac1x]=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon +x}\right)}{2 \varepsilon }-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x-\varepsilon }\right)}{2 \varepsilon }$$

and

$$D_{sym} [\cos \frac1x]=\frac{\cos \left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon +x}\right)}{2 \varepsilon }-\frac{\cos \left(\frac{1}{x-\varepsilon }\right)}{2 \varepsilon }$$

which are not defined at $x=\pm\varepsilon$ which is in agreement with the graphics but I cannot see anything more than that from the expressions.

Can anybody point out any method of obtaining graphics of similar functions at the interval measured in finite factor of $\varepsilon$?

Comment: I can't figure out what those graphics are supposed to be. e.g. there is a full period of $\sin$ between $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon / (1 + 2 \pi \epsilon)$. The graph of $\sin(1/x)$ should look like a solid rectangle.